# Reducers failing

Tags: apache, hadoop, mapreduce

We are using 3 cluster machine and mapreduce.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum property is set to 9. When I set no of reducer is equal to or less than 9 job is getting succeeded but if I set greater than 9 then it is failing with the exception "Task attempt_201701270751_0001_r_000000_0 failed to ping TT for 60 seconds. Killing!". Can any one guide me what will be the problem

Comment: Could you please go and see the logs of the reducer which is failing and provide the Stack error. Would be very useful to determine what is causing this error.

Comment: there is no error log except this 2017-01-20 08:16:37,536 INFO mapred.TaskTracker [main]: Task attempt_201612080512_0140_r_000003_1 failed to ping TT for 60 seconds. Killing!
2017-01-20 08:16:37,536 INFO mapred.TaskTracker [main]: About to purge task: attempt_201612080512_0140_r_000003_1

Comment: add reducer code, maybe the problem is you do not write to context and reducer becomes inactive

Comment: First thing I can think about is that reducer become inactive and it is being killed because of heart beat.

Comment: we have increased the heartbeat and also watched the memory usage it is fine and we are getting same issue instead of 60 sec it is replaced by newly added time. In my case max reducers can run in parallel is 9. so if i give no of reducers to 10 it is failing. But giving 9 or less than 9 it gets succeeded

Comment: What is the time for reducers to complete their respective taks?

Comment: As we have configured to start reducer after 95% of map is completed it takes about 5 minutes for initial copy phase and overall it takes 6 minutes

Comment: Have you discarded the option of maybe you don't have enough resources to start more than 9 reducers in parallel and they are waiting for resources from ResourceManager. Once resources are released from reducers completed, it's too late because it is already killed.

Comment: sorry we are using hadoop-0.20

Comment: Also yes we have checked we have enough memory to launch another set of 9 tasks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136758/discussion-between-dbustosp-and-wazza).

Comment: Hi we are using mapred.job.reuse.jvm.num.tasks to -1 whether this may cause any problem? @dbustosp

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be some bug in hadoop -0.20.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-1905 (for reference ).

Can you please try to increase the task timeout  ?

(mapreduce.task.timeout to a higher value ) ( **0 will disable the timeout** )