# No of reducers in mapreduce hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have only one key emitted from mapper to reducer and I have set no of reducers be 10. So one reducer will run on that key and what other remaining 9 reducers will do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other 9 reducers will run through their lifecycle as normal, they just wont have any key/values to process once they run, so they will stop quickly. Thus you will waste resources while they needlessly run.

You'll generally (most output formats do this) also find you end up with a part file for a reduce that ran but didnt write anything. The part file won't contain any actual data just file metadata, for example gzip headers.

Comment: Are those reducers, in any way, comparable to `IdentityReducer`?

Comment: They'll be whatever type of reducer the job has specified. If no reducer type has been set, it will run the default reducer which is an identity reducer.

Comment: @BinaryNerd Is there any way to solve this as we are getting some issue in this job?

Comment: Well this is the expected behaviour, what problem is it causing?

Comment: As i said we have only few keys less than no of reducers.. plz take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42484684/reducers-failing

Comment: @wazza why don't you set a smaller number of reducers? I guess this post is sufficiently answered by Binary Nerd and should be accepted. What you refer to is a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

The other 9 reducers will run until their slot time ends.

They will not have any K/V pairs to process and stop quickly.

You can use custom partitioners to distribute the map outputs to all reducers evenly; - atleast for first level; and finalaly combine through one reducer at very last phase - thus reducing computing load in most of reduce phase.